# Auto complete text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I followed [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/sharepoint-2010-jquery-autocomplete-textbox-containing-list/) to auto complete.

I am missing bunch of employee as I type. for example, I have a butler, jonathan but he is not showing up.

Comment: Looks like the default list view settings is playing a role. remember by default is 30 items per page. I changed the default view to 30000 and now all items are showing. but i really dont want to change this. I tried <QueryOptions>
    <RowLimit>30000</RowLimit>
  </QueryOptions> but it didn't do anything (while changed the default list view back to 30).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out rowLimit is case sensitive. and it's working now

```
var soapEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soapenv:Body> <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>Employees List</listName><viewFields><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='EmployeeName' /> </ViewFields></viewFields> <rowLimit>30000</rowLimit> </GetListItems> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>";

<rowLimit>30000</rowLimit>
```